# Adding attributes into a cart

Tags: ruby-on-rails, charts

On my product view below now I have 2 attributes I would like to pass with the photo.id
type.id and size.id

They will all be saved in the same line item

The button_to is an remote action so it does not leave the page after the button is pressed.

What would be the best way to add the attributes to be passed to the create in the line_items controller?

product view

```
    %b Paper Type

    = select(:type_id, :type, options_from_collection_for_select_with_attributes(Type.all, 'id', 'name', 'data-price', 'price'), { :include_blank=>false }, {:class => 'vars'})

  %p
    %b Paper Size

    = select(:type_id, :type, options_from_collection_for_select_with_attributes(Size.all, 'id', 'name', 'data-price', 'price'), { :include_blank=>false }, {:class => 'vars'})

  %p
    %b Total:
    %span#total
      %input{:type=>"hidden", value: @photo.price, name: 'price', id: 'baseprice'}

      = number_to_currency (@photo.price)

    %br
    = button_to 'Add to Cart', line_items_path(photo_id: @photo.id), remote: true
    %br
```

Line Items Controller

```
def create
photo = Photo.find(params[:photo_id])
@line_item = @cart.add_product(photo.id)

respond_to do |format|
  if @line_item.save
    format.html { redirect_to @line_item.cart }
    format.js { @current_item = @line_item }
    format.json { render action: 'show', status: :created, location: @line_item }
  else
    format.html { render action: 'new' }
    format.json { render json: @line_item.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
  end
 end
end
```

cart.rb model

```
def add_product(photo_id)
  current_item = line_items.find_by(photo_id: photo_id) 
  if current_item
      current_item.quantity = current_item.quantity.to_i + 1
  else
      current_item = line_items.build(photo_id: photo_id, quantity: 1)
  end
    current_item
end
```

cart initializer concerns/current_cart.rb

```
def set_cart 
  @cart = Cart.find(session[:cart_id])
  rescue ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound
    @cart = Cart.create
    session[:cart_id] = @cart.id
end
```

EDIT: to add cart initializer and add_product method

Comment: What is `add_product` in this line `@line_item = @cart.add_product(photo.id)` and where is `@cart` initialized?

Comment: I have a controller under concerns to initialize the cart and add_product is a method in the cart model to add line_itens with quantitylet. I'll update the initial post

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[**button_to**](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/UrlHelper.html#method-i-button_to)

`button_to` seems to be able to have params passed to the method, which are then rendered as `hidden fields`:

[image]

This means you *should* be able pass your extra attributes as parameters in the `button_to` method - allowing you to process them in your controller backend:

```
<%= button_to line_items_path(photo_id: @photo.id, type_id: "X", size_id: "Y") %>
```

--

**Form**

The problem with this is you can only pass the parameters if they are `static`. I see you're able to select them, which would lend itself entirely to having a `form` (specifically with [`form_tag`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormTagHelper.html#method-i-form_tag)):

```
<%= form_tag line_items_path(photo_id: @photo.id) do %>
   <%= select_tag :type_id .....%>
   <%= select_tag :size_id .....%>
   <%= submit_tag "Save" %>
<% end %>
```

*This* will allow you to send the params you need to your application above the scope of the `button_to` helper, allowing you to work the following in your backend:

```
params[:type_id]
params[:size_id] 

etc
```

Comment: in the case of the <%= button_to line_items_path(photo_id: @photo.id, type_id: "X", size_id: "Y") %> I would have to capture the values of the 2 select and pass then to the button_to when I select the values... now, how would I do that?

Comment: It'll have to be done with static values - that's why I detailed the `form_tag` way too :)

Comment: I'll try that and use a redirect back or redirect to the cart and see what happens